# Sorting and arranging a dictionary in python with datetime keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am having trouble while making a dictionary in python, I have a dictionary which keys are made of datetime data type, that is fetched from single dictionary, the problem is sometimes the dates are repeated in data which overwrites the same date. The format of the data looks like this:

```
{
"2020-09-09": [data],
"2020-09-08": [A],
"2020-09-08": [B],
"2020-09-07": [data],
"2020-09-08": [C]
}
```

In python, i wrote the code to make the dictionary like this,

```
row = dict({
            str(datetime.datetime.strptime(row.get('date'), '%Y-%m-%d').date()): [row]
        })
```

The output that i get from this, I am not sure how exactly i can reformat it, since the key cannot be repeat itself in a dictionary

```
{
"2020-09-09": [data],
"2020-09-08": [C],
"2020-09-07": [data],
}
```

desired output:

```
{
"2020-09-09": [data],
"2020-09-08": [[A],[B],[C]],
"2020-09-07": [data]
}
```

Comment: Your code `row = dict({  str(datetime.datetime.strptime(row.get('date'), '%Y-%m-%d').date()): [row]  }) ` cannot be execute as-is. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want us to understand how you built the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use collections.defaultdict

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
dd["1"].append(3)
dd["2"].append(4)
dd["1"].append(1)
dd["2"].append(2)

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': [3, 1], '2': [4, 2]})
```

if you want to have sorted list
after every append then you can make
custom implemetation of list with binary insertion

or sort manualy after adding values

```py
for el in dd.values():
    el.sort()
print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': [1, 3], '2': [2, 4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible suggestion. It is not very clear from your question where the data comes from, so I don't know how well this suggestion fits your needs.

```py
data_list = [
("2020-09-09", 'data1'),
("2020-09-08", 'A'),
("2020-09-08", 'B'),
("2020-09-07", 'data2'),
("2020-09-08", 'C')]

d = {}
for date,value in data_list:
  if date in d:
    d[date].append(value)
  else:
    d[date] = [value]

# d = {'2020-09-09': ['data1'], '2020-09-08': ['A', 'B', 'C'], '2020-09-07': ['data2']}
```

Alternatively, using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for date, value in data_list:
  d[date].append(value)

# d = defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'2020-09-09': ['data1'], '2020-09-08': ['A', 'B', 'C'], '2020-09-07': ['data2']})
```